# Autostart google-chrome with server ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, google-chrome-headless

Hi I would like to run this command line
google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222

After the server starts.( after Apache is started actually )
How can I acheive this ?
Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I tried to create a bash script
#!/bin/bash
#
# Bash script to setup headless google chrome

google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222

and in my crontab

@reboot /home/[user]/start/autostart-google.sh

where [user] is my user 
but it didn't worked